# Can parameters be passed between stylesheets?

Tags: xml, xslt, parameters

I am building a database in XML and displaying the data with xsl stylesheets.
Here is how the XML is broken down:

```
<store>
    <storeid>999</storeid>
    <storename>Grocery Store</storename>
    <storenumber></storenumber>
    <client>THE CLIENT</client>
    <street>999 Avenue Ave</street>
    <city>New York</city>
    <state>NY</state>
    <zip>99999</zip>
    <phone>9999999999</phone>
    <personnel>
        <name></name>
        <phone></phone>
    </personnel>
    <equipment></equipment>
    <servicelog>
        <record></record>
        <date></date>
        <storename></storename>
        <problem></problem>
        <technician></technician>
        <resolved></resolved>
    </servicelog>
</store>
```

What I'm trying to create is: Instead of displaying the 'equipment' element in the data table with the rest of the data, I'd like there to be a link displayed instead. This link will open a new window that will display the respective equipment data for that given store. (Clicking the equipment link for the first 'store' will open a new window displaying 'equipment' element for only that store. Like so:
[xslequipment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c4Np.jpg)

Hope this is a clear explanation. If I left any important info out, please let me know! I'm open to javascript solutions as well. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: So how do you use XSLT currently, called from a host language like PHP or Java or C# on the server? XSLT since version 1, i.e. from the beginning, knows global parameters declared by top-level `xsl:param` elements, but how you set them depends on the API of the XSLT processor or programming platform you use, unless you live in the XSLT 3 world and use the XPath 3.1 `transform` function to call XSLT from XSLT.

Comment: I don't understand the connection between your explanation of the problem and the title of the question. Why do you think that "passing parameters between stylesheets" is part of the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is this client-side XSLT or server-side XSLT?

With server-side, the traditional approach would be for the stylesheet to render the `equipment` element as a hyperlink (`a` element) using an `href` URI that the server recognizes as a request to display the appropriate equipment. The URI might contain the equipment key as a fragment identifier (after '#'), as a query parameter (after '?'), or as part of the URL path -- it really doesn't matter, so long as the server-side code knows what to do when it sees this URL request.

If you're working client side, the link would traditionally be generated with an `onclick` attribute that triggers a bit of Javascript to to an `XmlHttpRequest` (Ajax request) to the server to get the relevant resource, and then perhaps invoke another transformation to render that resource as HTML.

A more modern client-side-solution, more in tune with the "Web 2.0" approach, would be to use Saxon-JS, which allows you to do the event handling entirely within the XSLT stylesheet, so within a single stylesheet you can define a template rule with `match='equipment' mode='ixsl:onclick'` that causes the equipment to be rendered and the HTML page to be updated when the relevant link is clicked, without any need for another request to the server.